# Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /wso2am-3.2.0/repository\conf\advanced\qpid-config.xml (No such file or directory)

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I want to run wso2api manager 3.2.0 in linux, but I face following exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:/wso2am-3.2.0/repository\conf\advanced\qpid-config.xml (No such file or directory)
```

could you please guide me.

Comment: Are you running the server on Windows or Linux? Are you using a Deb installer or the Zip Binary to run the API Manager?

Comment: Thanks, I solved it. It was because of extract binary in windows then copy it to linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved. It was because of extract binary in windows then copy it to linux.